# Cannot store iBeacon RSSI values in an array

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, ibeacon, rssi

Trying to store all RSSI values in an NSMutablearray during the course of run time then finally output to the console. Have changed the value of x to 20000 to see if there are any changes in the value of the RSSI...unfortunately, no changes- Xcode reports 20000 values of the RSSI read in at the start of the code (not sure if this is an issue with sampling or ?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
rssiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
long newBeacon = 0;
if (beacon.rssi == newBeacon)
{

    newBeacon = beacon.rssi;
}

    else
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
            [rssiArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
            [rssiArray addObject:@(beacon.rssi)];
        }

    }
//Send array to console
NSLog (@"%@", [self rssiArray]);
```

The array is synthesized at the top of this same file like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize rssiArray;
```

The array is also defined in the ViewController.h here:

```
//array for storing RSSI values
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rssiArray;
```

@PaulW

So...

1. initialize the array in ViewController.m like this:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       rssiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
   }
   ```
2. Paste the following code into didRangeBeacons method within the AppDelegate.m like so...

   ```
       for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
               [rssiArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
               [rssiArray addObject:@(NOTSUREWHATGOESHERE???..WANT TO STORE RSSI)];
           }

       //Send array to console
       NSLog (@"%@", [self rssiArray]);
   ```

Comment: Is the declaration of `rssiArray` shown in context? ie. do you re-initialise `rssiArray` each time this method executes?  If so, that is your problem.  If not, please show your full method and array declaration in context

Comment: @Paulw11 - code updated to reflect your question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So it seems that you are initialising the array each time. This means that you will effectively throw away previous values. Is this code in `didRangeBeacons`?

Comment: @Paulw11 - Gotchya. May need help on telling whether that is being done or not. None of the above code is within didRangeBeacons. Should it be? The loop for the code above is located within ViewController.m. Thoughts?

Comment: That is why it helps to see the code in context- with the method names. You should initialize the array in viewDidLoad and add to it in didRangeBeacons.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks again. I am a student trying to learn the code- thank you for bearing with me. I updated the code (above). Is that what you were talking about or ?

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach that just stores rssi would be -

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
               inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {

    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        [self.rssiArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:beacon.rssi]];
    }
}
```

The reason that I say this is approach simplistic is that it simply stores rssi values into an array, regardless of which beacon they came from - as long as you are only ranging a single beacon at a time this won't be a problem.

By the way, you no longer need `@synthesize` directives and you should get into the habit of referring to properties via `self` rather than accessing the underlying iVar (which would be `_rssiArray` if you remove the `@synthesize`)